# Pentaho Kettle LDAP Output

Tags: ldap, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

**How do I update the LDAP value using LDAP Output Step in Spoon?**

I couldn't find any documentation on Pentaho's website. I am trying to update the group name of a particular user in Active Directory.

Until now, I was able to connect with the AD. But I can't make any changes to LDAP.

In General -> Settings, my operation is updated.

And in Fields -> Search Base, I defined the DC attributes. Eg: dc=xyz,dc=com.

And in Attributes, I defined the OU along with the value it should be changed too.

Is this how it should work?

I am getting an error saying

> cannot find DN(Distinguished Name) in the input stream!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are using the values you want to inject instead of the fields containing those values. This step heavily relies upon fields coming in from previous steps.

In the image below you will see I am passing in the 'dn' field which is used in Settings > 'Dn fieldname' to lookup the field I want to alter.

Then under Fields I am mapping the incoming 'new_name' field to the property 'givenName' on the LDAP object identified by the DN.

So my DN to lookup and the value to set the field to are coming from my transformation stream. I only statically identify the Attribute on the LDAP object to be mapped.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation. That explains a lot.
I followed the exact steps, but I still have a problem with the permissions to change the record. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0):

the dn is not right. dn is cn + ou-structure like ou + domain-structure like dc.

If you dont know the cn, you cant define the dn. You must take a LDAP-Input with query like your uid for getting dn.

With this dn you can update attributes with LDAP-Output, if you have rights for writing.